# Unique Count of Accounts contacted

Tags: reporting, salesforce-classic, custom-reports

Trying to find a way to determine how many unique people we contacted. People are in multiple campaigns, so searching by assigned didn't get me the results I wanted.

I tried searching for accounts with activity from the assigned users during a period of time, but that gets me everything (so if they're in 3 campaigns, they appear three times)

Is there any way for me to find out the unique number of people we talked to? Like, we called John Smith 3 times, but I only care we talked to John Smith during the time period.

I haven't tried the Power of One report yet, but from what I've read about it, that's not going to help me with counting anything unique.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a [Cross Filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_cross_filters_create.htm&type=5).

Your primary report type would be Contacts & Accounts, with a cross filter for "Contacts with Campaign Members" or "Contacts with Campaign History". (Campaign History is probably preferable, as it allows you to filter on fields on the Campaign itself, rather than just the Campaign Member). Then you'd add relevant date and status filters at the cross filter level to limit the span of activity you're interested in.

Note that since Campaign Members are Contacts, not Accounts, this does not deduplicate at the Account level, but you will get only a single row per Contact, regardless of how many campaigns that person was a participant in.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. I will report back. Thank you, this may be right on the money!